# XCode4: Why can I build with the developer code signing identity but the distribution one is greyed out?

Tags: iphone

I am able to build my project with the developer identity but the distribution identity is greyed out and I don't know why?

I've checked the bundleID matching.

It just seems odd one would work and not the other. Mmmm...

Any insight appreciated.

Comment: Does it do the same thing when trying to set both debug and release settings?

Comment: No. The developer code signing identity was fine. In release mode, the developer identify was greyed out. I suspected this was a naming mismatch somewhere....and it turned out to be a naming mismatch between the cert name and the portal provisioning profile name.

Comment: Glad you figured it out, certificates can be a headache. You should add an answer and accept it so that people know this question is resolved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. It was indeed a naming problem. When I changed the name of my portal distribution provisioning profile to iPhone Distribution, things worked out better. I knew to do this because I read in some docs the names on the cert in KeyChain Access must match that of the profile. Since, I couldn't change the cert name, changing the name in the portal did the trick. The cert added in KeyChain Access was done automagically by XCode. It named it "IPhone Distribution: ."

Answer (score 2):

You need to ensure you've created, downloaded, and installed your Distribution Provisioning profile (and also completed all other associated certificate work).  The Distribution Provisioning Profile is different than the Development Profile (and thus you can't build with your distribution id if you don't have the provisioning profile setup).

Comment: The distribution was created in the portal and the provisioning profile appears in the organizer as expected. However, it cannot be selected as a code signing identity. Again, it is greyed out. Is there some other step here you are suggesting?

Comment: Does the grey'd out text provide an error message or anything?

Comment: I figured out the problem. It was indeed a naming problem. When I changed the name of my provisioning profile to iPhone Distribution, things worked out better. I knew to do this because I read the names on the cert in KeyChain Access must match that of the profile. Since, I couldn't change the cert name, changing the name in the portal did the trick.